# google app engine: getting error #1000 when I try to add url for custom web address

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

First off, I have been trying to configure my domain from the normal "appID.appspot.com" to my own custom "www.domainName.com" I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=47283) to set up my domain's CNAME and then I followed the instructions to change your @ name to also redirect my naked domain to my web url.

Then I followed the directions for decoupling the domain from google sites so that I can then add the domain to my google app engine app (from google apps dash going to settings-> and then clicking on my app engine app on the left -> then clicking add new web url in the web address section).

However, when I try to do that, I keep getting the 1000 error.  Has anyone else been able to map a custom domain to their app engine application?  Currently, when I type in my domain, it seems to be redirecting to the "appId.appspot.com"  instead of the new domain.

Here's a [screenshot of error #1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjsnL.png) as contributed by @Roger Thomas.

Comment: What is "the 1000 error"? Please give us more details - preferably a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry to post a "me too", but I'm having exactly the same error.